# Angular selectize directive - I can't type in input when I select empty option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-select

I use [angular selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) with these options:

```
$rootScope.mySelectize = {
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'label',
    searchField: ['label'],
    maxItems: 1
};
```

and in view:

```
<selectize 
    config='mySelectize' 
    name="country" 
    options='referenceData.country' 
    ng-model="vm.searchForm.countryId">
</selectize>
```

Problem: when I select an option, lets say Germany and after I change it to empty option, I can't type into the input, I must delete this empty option from my keyboard to be able to type again.

Any idea how I can reset/clear this option if the user switch between an option with value and one empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, which was ok, this is reset my input:

```
$rootScope.mySelectize = {
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'label',
    searchField: ['label'],
    maxItems: 1,
    *onChange: function(value) {
        var self = this;
        var value = value || "";
        if (!value.length) { 
            self.clear();
            return;
        }
    }*
};
```

If somebody else will have this problem...